# How to configure keep-alive timeout in playframework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, netty, keep-alive

I use playframework 2.0 in production and I see a rapidly growing number of files open by the corresponding java process. I changed the default allowed number of open files for a process from 1024 to 4096, but this just delays a problem and after some time the number of open files becomes so big, that the server slows down and sometimes even a `java.net.SocketException` "too many open files" appears in a log.

I use ubuntu server 12.04, sun jdk 1.7.0_09.

`lsof` command demonstrates that almost all of open files are sockets created for user connections, so I make a conclusion that the Netty server that is used by playframework keeps alive a lot of open connections. As far as I understand I should change the keep-alive behaviour of the Netty server, for example, to set a low keep-alive timeout. How can I configure this in playframework 2.0? Or may be the problem is in something else? I can provide any configuration if needed.

**UPD:** here is a bit of output of `lsof -aPn -p 12251`. I censored some parts of ips with `***`

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
java    12251 root  324u  IPv6             279502      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.65.137:51506 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  325u  IPv6             286749      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.18.121:1624 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  327u  IPv6             287220      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.126.210:49244 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  330u  IPv6             279289      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.65.155:12444 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  331u  IPv6             285609      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.33.233:2552 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  332u  IPv6             285610      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.33.233:2554 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  333u  IPv6             287236      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.90.20:16040 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  334u  IPv6             284047      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.195.2:1175 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  335u  IPv6             279357      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.65.137:51273 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12251 root  336u  IPv6             279988      0t0    TCP 10.127.0.***:80->***.***.65.137:51287 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it comes from Play ? Don't you generate some kind of files in your app ?

Comment: I don't generate or read any files from a File System, all resources were automatically packed inside an application jar. And if I test what files are open by means of an `lsof` utility, I see that this files are unix sockets directed to a lots of different IPs, so I think that this sockets are connected to users. And they do not correspond, for example, to connections to my databases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Play without any HTTP server you can [manipulate the response headers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaResponse) before sending the `Result` ([Scala version](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaResults)) , otherwise you need to check settings of the front-end server.

```
response().setHeader(CONNECTION, "Keep-Alive");
response().setHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=10");
return ok(index.render());
```

Note, that these values are sample and I don't know if they will fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I don't use any other HTTP server. It seems this is all I need, I will test.

Comment: BTW, try to ask a question on the google group, there are more geeks, so maybe somebody will identify your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not make this work. I tested it on my local computer, set timeout=1, max=1, but connections hang for a long time. They are closed by themselfs independently of whether I add headers or not.
I read that this headers are mostly for diagnostics, so they hardly influence the behaviour of the server.
Moreover, It is very hard to alsways set this headers, there are a lot of controllers in the program, and there are also controllers that are not written by me, for example the Assets controller.

Comment: I observed same behavior after publishing the answer, however the code sets the headers properly.

Comment: Yes, the headers are right. Now I tried to ask in the google group. No link now because of the premoderation.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? the need for this configuration seems quite universal. I think the modern solution comes from here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1120